# apollo-link setContext converts all headers to lower case

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I've encountered issue when setting headers with `operation.setContext`.
See code below:

```js
const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const { tokenHeaderName, tokenHeaderValue } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'))

  // add the authorization to the headers
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      [tokenHeaderName]: tokenHeaderValue,
    },
  })

  return forward(operation)
})
```

With this peace of code I simply want to inject custom authorization header with token. My header name is, let's say: `X-CustomToken-XYZ`. Java backend token processor is **case-sensitive** unlike the standard web headers.

The problem: *ApolloLink* for some reason converts all headers that are passed, to **lower case** (I checked it by hardcoding the `X-CustomToken-XYZ` in string litterals) hence the authorization logic in our app simply doesn't work.

I've tried using either `@apollo/link-context` and `apollo-link-context` both behaves similarly.

Any suggestions on how to pass my headers to the request as is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like it's more likely being caused by either your browser or whatever fetch library you might be using, as opposed to ContextLink or ApolloClient.

Comment: specs: every header consumer (your token processor) should work in case-insensitive way